# transforming foreign constraints in raven document db

Tags: ravendb, document-database

I have following entity "MyEntity" in my **RavenDb**

```
{
  Id: {Guid}
  //...
  //...
}
```

In the application there might occur a specific event relating to elements of **MyEntity**.
Not I want to associate users (also in db of course) with this type of event in order to allow the eventhandler to handle the event only if there is a relation between **MyEntity** and **User**

Using **MySQL** I'd create a table which which aggregates MyEntity.Id with User.Id (and possibly a specific EventId) 1:x (x element N) so that I can query all items with a a specific Id (MyEntitiy.Id) and the corresponding User.Id

Is it okay to simply apply this approach to a document db like **RavenDb**? Or should I consider something else?

Answer (score 1):

Relations between documents in **RavenDB** is implemented in the following way:

A document can reference any other document from the database by storing the referenced document ID in the document. Referenced documents are called: **Related Documents.**

For example, document *employees/3-A* is referring to *document employees/2-A*:

```
{
    "LastName": "Leverling",
    "FirstName": "Janet",
    "ReportsTo": "employees/2-A",
}
```

These related documents can be 'loaded', 'indexed' & 'queried on'.

Learn more about document Modeling & working with multiple documents in the following links:

- [Document Modeling](https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch03/Ch03.md#document-modeling)
- [Working with multiple documents](https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch02/Ch02.md#working-with-multiple-documents)
- [Handle Document Relationships](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/client-api/how-to/handle-document-relationships#client-api--how-to-handle-document-relationships)